# CI page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

[page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2oKN.png)

**My htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Email', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Email', 'required|trim');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        # code...
        $data['title'] = 'Login';
        $this->load->view('templates/auth_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
        $this->load->view('templates/auth_footer');
    } else {
        $this->_login();
    }
}
```

anyone know my problem? I think my syntax is correct but the page is still not found.
anyone help me, I'm still a beginner in the field of programmers

Comment: do you have routing files for this? 
I can see that this is your controller, but maybe the issue is comming from the route code, could you please share this briefly?.

Comment: check your .htaccess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    **First, you check, that the post data is checked if the condition or else condition inside echo and exit the post data.**
    
    public function index()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Email', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Email', 'required|trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      echo " If stmt ";
 exit();
            # code...
            $data['title'] = 'Login';
           
        } else {
      echo " else stmt";
     exit();
            $this->_login();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this htaccess file in application folder.It may helps

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Your htaccess file is in outside the application folder.This was also needed.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: the file already exists, thanks for the response

Comment: just load login view file in index.Conditions and all write in another function.

Answer (score -1):

Please change your file name like (auth/Login) first letter capital

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).